# Help with Date Formula Field

Tags: formula, date

I'm trying to create a Date Formula field that will check and see if the Date Value that will be placed into that field is still within the same month as another field and then if it is populate the field. If not then leave it blank.

Also, the Month_Copy__c field below is a text field that will display the month like August.

```
IF(
TEXT(MONTH(End_Date_W4__c + 3)) = Month_Copy__c, 
End_Date_W4__c + 3, 
null)
```

So, If End Date + 3 days is still in the month August then go ahead and populate this field with End Date + 3 Days, if not then null. I just tested this and the field is returning null when it should be populated. Thanks

Comment: What does month copy contain?

Comment: @Abhijeet please re-read the question. I stated that it is a text field that will display the month.

Comment: i asked what value it contains- number of the month or name of month ?

Comment: That is also stated above, it will display text (i.e. August, September, October)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TEXT(MONTH(End_Date_W4__c + 3)) returns a number and you are comparing it against a String like "August".In any case , it will never give you the correct value.You need to either make them both numbers or both as Strings

Comment: Can you please add to your answer how I would make TEXT(MONTH(...)) as a text value to compare?

Comment: Actually never mind. I changed my process to fit this better. I changed the Month_Copy__c field to return the month number instead. Figured that would be easier than the other route. It is working now. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Glad that i helped you.Request you to mark this as the solution so that others may benefit from this :)